# compareToIgnoreCase doesn't work with Strings.xml

Tags: android, xml

In my code, I've got a array of all the apps that are installed on the device, in which I want to find the app I'm running itself. To accomplish this I wrote the following code:

```
if (tmpPacs[I].packageName.compareToIgnoreCase("com.example.basiclauncher") == 0){
    launcherPosition = I;
}
```

This line works perfectly, however, I want to store **"com.example.basiclauncher"** in a string in **strings.xml** like so:

```
<string name="launcher_package">com.example.basiclauncher</string>
```

And change the line to:

```
if (tmpPacs[I].packageName.compareToIgnoreCase("@string/launcher_package") == 0){
    launcherPosition = I;
}
```

This doesn't work, **launcherPosition** stays 0 throughout the execution of the code and the correct app isn't found. When I revert to the first line, the app is found again. Why is this? And how can I make this work with the strings.xml file?

EDIT:

I just now realised I was trying to use xml code inside my java class, which obviously isn't going to work. Thanks for all the quick replies, **getPackageName()** is a much more elegant solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to retrieve the string from the xml, you have to use `getResources().getString(R.string. launcher_package)`. You can also retrieve the package name through `getPackageName()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do

`tmpPacs[1].packageName.compareToIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.launcher_package));`

The code you have is literally comparing tmpPacs[I].packageName to the string "@string/launcher_package" instead of the string resource it refers to.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `"@string/launcher_package"`.

Try this:

```
tmpPacs[I].packageName.compareToIgnoreCase(
              getResources().getString(R.string. 
                                        launcher_package))
```

Hope this helps.